# Fluent API - Use candidate key as Foreign Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have following two entities. **Employee and Address.** 
Employee can have one or many addresses. 

What i need is to set their relationship via Fluent APIs. But i don't want EmployeeId (which is primary key in Employee) to use as foreign key for Address. Instead i want to use Guid from Employee as Foreign key in Address.

In a nutshell, i want 

**Employee 1:N Address**, but based on 
 
**Guid from Employee -> Guid in Address**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId;
    public Guid Guid;
    .
    .
    .
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses;
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId
    public Guid Guid; // Guid from Employee 
    .
    .
}
```

Please help me how to set this relationship. That's 
1. One employee can have many addresses. 
2. Employee.Guid will be foreign key in Address.Guid

Comment: No. I want to use AddressId as key.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: You have to create employeeId in address table then only you can create one 2 many relationship
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: You don't need this at all: `public Guid Guid; // Guid from Employee `. Why would you? You can cheaply query what `Employee`'s have a given `Address`, because `Address` is keyed by `AddressId`...furthermore, two `Employee`'s might have the same address, although uncommon, so don't store redundant data.